# How do we find the derivative of the following function: $F(x)=\sin\Big(\int_0^x \sin\big(\int_0^y \frac{1}{1+t^4}\ dt\big)\ dy\Big)$ using FTC.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Find the derivative of the following function:

$F(x)=\sin\Big(\int_0^x \sin\big(\int_0^y \frac{1}{1+t^4}\ dt\big)\ dy\Big)$

I tried applying fundamental theorem of calculus directly but the the integral $\int_0^y \frac{1}{1+t^4}\ dt$ is giving me problems, I started by deriving both sides with respect to x, and by chain rule, the derivative should be f'(g(x))*g'(x). I reached this point and couldn't complete, does anyone have the key for the solution?

Comment: Why do you think you need to evaluate this integral? They might mean that you just write the expression you get after using the fundamental theorem, without any further simplification. Either way, if you do want to calculate it, you can find the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+t^4}$ by first decomposing $1+t^4$ into the product of two quadratic polynomials and then using partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: what is f and g?

Comment: i think he means the chain rule there @cineel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we are trying to find:

$$\text{p}'\left(x\right):=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin\left(\underbrace{\int_0^x\sin\left(\int_0^y\frac{1}{1+t^4}\space\text{d}t\right)\space\text{d}y}_{:=\space\text{z}\left(x\right)}\right)\right)\tag1$$

First we use the cain rule, in order to write:

$$\text{p}'\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin\left(\text{z}\left(x\right)\right)\right)=\cos\left(\text{z}\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\text{z}'\left(x\right)\tag2$$

Now, we must find $\text{z}'\left(x\right)$:

$$\text{z}'\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_0^x\underbrace{\sin\left(\int_0^y\frac{1}{1+t^4}\space\text{d}t\right)}_{:=\space\text{k}\left(y\right)}\space\text{d}y\right)\tag3$$

Using FTC (by definition), we can see:

$$\text{z}'\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_0^x\text{k}\left(y\right)\space\text{d}y\right)=\text{k}\left(x\right)\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\text{p}'\left(x\right)=\cos\left(\text{z}\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\text{k}\left(x\right)=$$
$$\cos\left(\int_0^x\sin\left(\int_0^y\frac{1}{1+t^4}\space\text{d}t\right)\space\text{d}y\right)\cdot\sin\left(\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^4}\space\text{d}t\right)\tag5$$